# Float a TextView to the top of a TableRow

Tags: android, layout, tablerow

I have two `TextView` in my `TableRow`, but one of them has a large text. I want the first `TextView` to float to the top of the `TableRow`:

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/trLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/location"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:textSize="50dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="1234"
                  android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </TableRow>
```

I tried using `layout_gravity` and `gravity`, but they both have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/trLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1234"
            android:textSize="50dp" />
    </TableRow>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This would introduce some redundancy. When I change the textsize, I also have to change two `layout_height`s.

Comment: You will not need to change in two places if you use the dim.xml to set your numerical values like textSize